# Java Image Rotation does not work properly

Tags: java, image, class, rotation

Hello fellow programmers,

I am making a game and I want to be able to rotate my images.
I dont use Graphics2d because i made the render class myself(Mostly).

The problem is that my current rotation method leaves holes in the new (rotated) picture it also does not place the new pixels on the right spot...

I dont see the problem so maybe you can help :)

```
    public void drawRotatedImage(Image image, int offX, int offY, double degree){
    int Iwidth = image.width;
    int Iheight = image.height;

    double angle = Math.toRadians(degree);
    double sin = Math.sin(angle);
    double cos = Math.cos(angle);
    double x0 = 0.5 * (Iwidth  - 1);     // point to rotate about
    double y0 = 0.5 * (Iheight - 1);     // center of image

    for(int x = 0; x < Iwidth; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < Iheight; y++){
            double a = x - x0;
            double b = y - y0;
            int xx = (int) (+a * cos - b * sin + x0);
            int yy = (int) (+a * sin + b * cos + y0);

            if(xx >= 0 && xx < width && yy >= 0 && yy < height){
                setPixel(x+offX, y+offY, image.pixels[xx + yy*image.width]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the setpixel function looks like this:

```
 public void setPixel(int x, int y, int color){
    if((x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height) || color == 0xffff00ff){
        return;
    }
    pixels[x + y * width] = color;


}
```

This works fine for non rotated images... but when i rotate it gives weird shit
Except when i use an perfect square as image and then rotate like 90 or 180
But otherwise i get back images full of holes and wrong pixels....

So to be clear it is not a bug or something like that... im just on the lookout for a better solution or something to fill the holes.

Comment: Why not simply  `x0 = 0.5 * Iwidth` &&  `y0 = 0.5 * Iheight` ?

Comment: Because that is not the middle

Comment: watch your language  this is not your backyard!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the source(original) point with the color of destination before rotation:

```
 setPixel(x+offX, y+offY, image.pixels[xx + yy*image.width]);// you get the color of destination (xx,yy) and set it to source (x,y).
```

That is why it works when the degree is 180 because the reverse of the operation looks right while it is still reversed.

The correct way is:

```
setPixel(xx+offX, yy+offY, image.pixels[x+ y*image.width]);
```

Comment: okay that was my bad indeed... but i still get holes in my new image...